# Getting Error in calling apex method from Button action

Tags: apex, visualforce, ajax-toolkit

Can somebody help me with this code
I am trying to change the value if the Validated__c field to true whenever the button is clicked.

Class Code:

```
global class checkbox{
    webservice static void check(Id localId) { 
        Account acc = new Account();
        system.debug(localId);
        system.debug('localId');
        acc.Id = localId ;
        acc.Validated__c = true;
        update acc;
    }
}
```

Button Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
alert("This is it!");
if({!Account.Validated__c}=true)
{
    sforce.apex.execute("checkbox","check",{localId:"{!Account.Id}"});   
    alert("This is it!");
}
```

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: And when I am trying to run this class via developer console like this: checkbox.check(00128000002kYzm); (Passing some account's ID)
It is showing error: Line: 1, Column: 26
expecting a right parentheses, found 'kYzm'

Comment: If I've understood correctly then you want to mark `Validated__c` to true on click of button, right? Then why are you checking `Account.Validated__c = true` ?? (BTW, condition is also wrong, there should be one extra `=` if you want to check)

Comment: Yeah you got it right.

Comment: And btw if I am trying like:
 acc.Validated__c == true;
 Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be a statement at line 7 column 17

Comment: So if you want to update that, then just call the method. no need to check for condition in my opinion

Comment: Could you please suggest me edits in my code?
That would be of great help

Comment: First tell me, is `Account` a property? that you are trying to access in javascript?

Comment: No, account is standard object. And I am trying to pass the id of account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27744/discussion-between-abbas-and-happy).

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax around the execute statement is incorrect, I think you need to use single quotes here as it is being interpreted by Salesforce still and not JavaScript:

```
var retStr; // good to catch a return value, if any (I dont remember)
sforce.apex.execute("checkbox","check",{localId:'{!Account.Id}'}); //note single quotes, not double quotes in final parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling a apex class from javacscript using AJAX toolkit, you could do the update in AJAX toolkit itself like below

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
var newRecords = [];
var A = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 
A.id ="{!Account.Id}"; 
A.Validated__c = 'true';
newRecords.push(A); 
var result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
```

Hope it helps.